# Need help setting up an Access query

Tags: ms-access-2010

An example of what I'm trying to do is given below.  For each person, I want a query that will look at each reason and calculate a sum of points based on: if A-F are present the points will be calculated as follows for John 10+20+30+40+50-60, i.e., A+B+C+D+E-F.  If F isn't present, then it's a straight sum of the points (for Paul).

```
ID  name    points  reason
1   John    10  A
2   John    20  B
3   John    30  C
4   John    40  D
5   John    50  E
6   John    60  F
7   Paul    5   A
8   Paul    10  B
9   Paul    15  C
10  Paul    20  D
11  Paul    25  E
```

Comment: Can there be any other reasons besides A-F? That is, is F the only reason you subtract? Use a GROUP-BY with a SUM of an IIF function that uses points unless reason=F then use -points (negation)

Comment: Yes, F is the only reason I would subtract.   I will try your suggestion, Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Select [name], 
    Sum(IIF([reason] = "F", -[points], [points])) As TotalPoints
From YourTable
Group By [name]
```

Learn more about iif here: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/iif-function-32436ecf-c629-48a3-9900-647539c764e3

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between `10+20+30+40+50-60` and what you call *a straight sum*.

So, all you need is to *group by* the name:

```sql
Select [name], Sum([points]) As TotalPoints
From YourTable
Group By [name]
```

Comment: Notice that he's subtracting the "F" score - not adding. It caught me too first time.

Comment: @n8wrl: Oh, missed that subtle detail.

Comment: Thanks, but the values are all positive.  F is not a negative number, so a sum of of the points would not be correct.  A work around would be to create two tables with sums of A-E and one of F and then create another query to subtract F from the summed table for each name.

Comment: Yes, missed the minus, sorry. However, @n8wrl did provide the solution, so please mark that as the answer.